# How do I make a view all button in reactJs (state array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, plaid

I am working with plaid API and I want to view all of my transactions from my endpoint but I keep receiving a 300 error. However, When I used this endpoint earlier I went through perfectly with no errors. In fact, even when I use postman I am able to receive the data. I tried playing alot with the dependency array in the useeffect method.

Blocks.js

```
const Blocks = props => {
    useEffect(() => {
        props.blocksData()      
      },[props])

return (
"hi")
function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log(state)
  return {
      blocks:state.blockReducer.blocks,
      random:"hi"
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  blocksData
   }

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Blocks)
```

userBlocks.js

```
export function blocksData(data){
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(blocksLoading());
        return axios.get('https://lambda-budget-blocks.herokuapp.com/plaid/transactions/1')
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(blocksSuccess(response.data.categories))
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                dispatch(blocksFailure(error)); 
            })
    }
}
```

NOTHING IS WRONG WITH THE REDUX SET UP BTW

Comment: what error are you seeing? Also, think you need to provide more code.

Comment: A 300 error in react and a 200 in postman

Comment: what does it say in the console ?

Comment: The HTTP 300 Multiple Choices redirect status response code indicates that the request has more than one possible responses. The user-agent or the user should choose one of them. As there is no standardized way of choosing one of the responses, this response code is very rarely used

Comment: if you put that url on the browser it fails. so there is a problem with the backend.

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 300
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)

Comment: It was working earlier though